# When I use element.ClassList in for loop it store only first element class and other are undefined

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

When I use console.log to print `allbu[i].classList[i]` it print only first element class right and all other class name are shown undefined

```js
var allbu = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

var buttoncopy = []
for (let i = 0; i < allbu.length; i++) {
  buttoncopy.push(allbu[i].classList[i]);
}
console.log(buttoncopy);

function buchange(btc) {
  if (btc.value == 'red') {
    btcred();
  } else if (btc.value == 'blue') {
    btcblue();
  } else if (btc.value == 'green') {
    btcgreen();
  }
}

function btcred() {
  for (let i = 0; i < allbu.length; i++) {
    allbu[i].classList.remove(allbu[i].classList[i]);
    allbu[i].classList.add('redbu');
  }
}

function btcblue() {
  for (let i = 0; i < allbu.length; i++) {
    allbu[i].classList.remove(allbu[i].classList[i]);
    allbu[i].classList.add('bluebu');
  }
}

function btcgreen() {
  for (let i = 0; i < allbu.length; i++) {
    allbu[i].classList.remove(allbu[i].classList[i]);
    allbu[i].classList.add('greenbu');
  }
}
```

```css
#con {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
}

#con1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 5px;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

select {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.redbu {
  background-color: red;
}

.bluebu {
  background-color: royalblue;
}

.greenbu {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.yellowbu {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Button Color</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jj3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="con">
    <h1>Change button Color</h1>
    <div id="con1">
      <form>
        <select id="colour" onchange="buchange(this)">
          <option value="random">Random</option>
          <option value="red">Red</option>
          <option value="blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="green">Green</option>
          <option value="reset">Reset</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <button class="redbu">Red</button>
      <button class="bluebu">blue</button>
      <button class="greenbu">green</button>
      <button class="yellowbu">yellow</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="jj3.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the index from the class list. It's enough if you iterate through the elements only:

```
for(let i=0;i < allbu.length;i++){
    buttoncopy.push( allbu[i].classList );
}
```